# Desplegables con valores únicos Laravel y Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire

Quiero realizar un desplegable Único dependiendo de otro desplegable

tengo 3 tablas

```
areas
    +------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | name       | varchar(255)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
    | code       | int(11)          | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
    | created_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | updated_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    +------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
categories
    +------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | name       | varchar(255)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
    | created_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | updated_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    +------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 categyareas
    +--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | id_category  | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
    | id_area      | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
    | ans_cat      | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | duration_cat | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | description  | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | created_at   | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | updated_at   | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    +--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Lo que quiero es que al seleccionar categoría(1) y el area(1), en siguiente, al seleccionar categoría(1) no muestre el area(1), ya que ya existe esa relacion

Investigue y realice este consulta

```
SELECT name
FROM areas 
where id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT  id_area
    FROM categoryareas WHERE 
    id_area IN (
        SELECT id_area FROM categoryareas WHERE id_category = 1
    )
)
```

la cual ejecuto y me da el resultado que quiero [Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5b37d/1/0)

En esta imagen si observo en la tabla principal ya existe una relacion con Categoría 2 y Area 5, al ingresar un nuevo registro me sigue apareciendo area 5 con categoría 2, el cual areas 5 ya no debería aparecer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en mi controlador tengo

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Categoryarea;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\area\Area;
use App\Models\category\Category;
use App\Models\categoryarea\categoryarea;

class CreateCategoryArea extends Component
{
    public $selecteArea = null, $selecteCategory = null;
    public $areas, $categories, $ans_cat = null;
    public $CategoryAreaStore = false, $results, $categoriaSel;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.categoryarea.create-category-area');
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->areas = Area::all();
        $this->categories = Category::all();
    }

    function rules() {
        return [
        'selecteArea' => 'required',
        'selecteCategory' => 'required',
        'ans_cat' => '',
        ];
    }

    public function updated($propertyName)
    {
        $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
    }

    protected $messages = [
        'selecteArea.required' => 'Selecione una Area',
        'selecteCategory.required' => 'Selecione una Categoria',
    ];

    public function save(){

        $this->validate();

        categoryarea::create([
            'id_area'=> intVal($this->selecteArea),
            'id_category'=> intVal($this->selecteCategory),
            'ans_cat' => $this->ans_cat,
        ]);
        $this->emit('CategoryAreaStore');
        $this->resetErrorBag();
        $this->resetValidation();
        $this->reset(['selecteArea', 'selecteCategory', 'ans_cat']);
        $this->emitTO( 'categoryarea.live-category-area-table','render');
        $this->emit('alert', 'Relacion categorya por area creado sastifactoriamente');
    }

    public function cerrar(){
        $this->reset(['selecteArea', 'selecteCategory','ans_cat']);
        $this->emit('CategoryAreaStore');
        $this->resetErrorBag();
        $this->resetValidation();
    }
}
```

y mi codigo esta esto

```
        <div class="col-lg">
            <div class="input-icon">
                <span class="input-icon-addon">
                    <i class="fas fa-clone"></i>
                </span>
                <select class="form-control" wire:model="selecteCategory">
                    <option value="">{{ __('Select Category') }} *</option>
                    @foreach ($categories as $category)
                        <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <x-jet-input-error for="selecteCategory" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row row-sm">
        <div class="col-lg">
            <div class="input-icon">
                <span class="input-icon-addon">
                    <i class="fas fa-clone"></i>
                </span>
                <select class="form-control" wire:model="selecteArea">
                    <option value="">{{ __('Select Area') }} *</option>
                    @foreach ($areas as $area)
                        <option value="{{ $area->id }}">{{ $area->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <x-jet-input-error for="selecteArea" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Este es mi modelo categoryarea

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\categoryarea;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class categoryArea extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function area()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\area\Area' , 'id_area', 'id');
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\category\Category' , 'id_category', 'id');
    }
}
```

Modelo area

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\area;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Area extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function functionaries()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\functionary\Functionary' , 'area_id', 'id');
    }

    public function categoryareas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\categoryarea\categoryarea' , 'id_area', 'id');
    }

    public function activitycategoryareas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\activitycategoryarea\activitycategoryarea', 'id_area', 'id');
    }
}
```

Modelo category

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\category;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function categoryarea()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\categoryarea\Categoryarea' , 'id_category', 'id');
    }

    public function activitycategoryarea()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\activitycategoryarea\activitycategoryarea', 'id_category', 'id');
    }
}
```

Lo cual no se como realizar ese proceso.

Comment: Eso es todo en tu controlador?

Comment: No, ya pongo todo el controlador

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré una solución y hasta ahora va bien.

en mi controlador adicione esta **Function** Y publique la variable

```
 public $categoryareas;

    public function updatedselecteCategory($id)
    {
        $this->categoryareas = categoryarea::where('id_category', $id)->get();
        $this->select = $this->categoryareas->pluck('id_area');
        $this->categoryareas = area::whereNotIn('id', $this->select)->get();
    }
```

y en la vista remplace este codigo

```
<div class="row row-sm">
        <div class="col-lg">
            <div class="input-icon">
                <span class="input-icon-addon">
                    <i class="fas fa-clone"></i>
                </span>
                <select class="form-control" wire:model="selecteArea">
                    <option value="">{{ __('Select Area') }} *</option>
                    @foreach ($areas as $area)
                        <option value="{{ $area->id }}">{{ $area->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <x-jet-input-error for="selecteArea" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Por este código

```
<div class="row row-sm">
    <div class="col-lg">
        @if (empty($selecteCategory))
            <span class="text-danger error">No hay selecionada una categoria</span>
        @else
            <div class="row row-sm">
                <div class="col-lg">
                    <div class="input-icon">
                        <span class="input-icon-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-clone"></i>
                        </span>
                        <select class="form-control" wire:model="selecteArea">
                            <option value="">-- Select Area --</option>
                            @foreach ($categoryareas as $item)
                                <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    @error('selecteArea') <span
                        class="text-danger error">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Gracias y espero que les sirva de referencia para sus proyectos

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de conseguir ese comportamiento, como no conozco como has nombrado a las relaciones en el modelo tomare como función "areas" la relación pivote con categoría, tampoco veo en tu controlador las variables publicas llamadas selectedArea o selectedCategoria, pero selectedCategoria debería de ser un modelo de Categoria, en este caso para poder traer la relación con sus areas y comprobar si tiene dicha relacion ya con el area o no.

```html
  <select class="form-control" wire:model="selecteArea">
     <option value="">{{ __('Select Area') }} *</option>
     @foreach ($areas as $area)
        <option value="{{ $area->id }}" 
             @if($categoriaSel->areas->contains('id', $area->id))
               disabled 
             @endif
         >
        {{ $area->name }}
        </option>
     @endforeach
  </select>
```

También se me ocurre otro modo, que seria comprobar el cambio del selector de la categoría para traer solo las areas que no tienen relación con ellas y cargarlas dinámicamente tras el cambio de categoría.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta. Efectivamente me equivoque de controlador y publique el que no era, ya lo corregí y adicione los 3 modelos para una visual mas  amplia... intente seguir tu ejemplo, pero no lo pude hacer funcionar. Mil disculpa por mi error.. Gracias

Comment: Vale veo que has creado un modelo en lo que seria la tabla pivote, se puede hacer pero quizás yo no te lo recomendaría, echa un vistazo a como Laravel recomienda trabajar con las tablas pivote https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many